# using NSPredicate with a set of answers

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate, runtime-error, nsset

I have a set of strings containing personIDs and I have a NSFetchedResults of people managedObjects with unique strPersonIDs.  I tried to create an NSPredicate but it fails.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I'm a bit new to NSPredicate so be kind.

```
NSSet *zipSet = [NSSet setWithSet:[self getziplist:searchText]];
searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(strPersonID IN %@)",zipSet];
NSPredicate *searchPersonPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:searchString];
```

The runtime error message is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(strPersonID IN {(
    300040,
    300082,
    412218
)})"'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't interpolate `zipSet` into the string, interpolate it into the predicate:

```
NSSet *zipSet = [NSSet setWithSet:[self getziplist:searchText]];
NSPredicate *searchPersonPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"strPersonID IN %@",zipSet];
```

If you interpolate the NSSet into a string, it won't have the correct format (NSString uses `-description`, which uses the old NextStep [property list format](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/description)).

Comment: outis - could you help with an example of this?  I'm not sure I know what you mean by interpolate.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jangelo42: My answer above already has an example. Take a closer look at the source code snippet. [Interpolate](http://www.onelook.com/?w=interpolate) and [string interpolation](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22string+interpolation%22) are defined online.

Comment: @jangelo42: if you're curious about the different formats (which illustrate what's invalid and what's valid), add the line that sets `searchString` from your original code to your current code and use a debugger to inspect the values of `searchString` and `[searchPersonPredicate predicateFormat]`.