# Dealing with NSPredicate and arguments with quotes (not necessarily paired)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Let's say I have quotes inside the string I need to search, for example:

```
 This "is 'a complicated string
```

This is the code:

```
NSPredicate* thePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"editionString=\"String \"With Quotes\""];
```

This line of code makes my app to crash because the predicate is no longer understood:

```
Unable to parse the format string "editionString="String "With Quotes""
```

I don't want to remove the quotes because I need to compare such string with the string I have on my local database, and they need to be identical (the local one contains the quotes as well).

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [using NSPredicate with a set of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418027/using-nspredicate-with-a-set-of-answers)

Comment: @outis Are you sure ? I've extended my question

Comment: Seems like you have 2 escaped quotes on the LHS and only 1 on the RHS.

Comment: @piobyz I know, that's the point. How to handle with strings containing quotes

Comment: Also: how do you use this predicate and what is error message when your app crashes?

Comment: @piobyz Unable to parse the format string "editionString=""String With Quotes""

Comment: See this doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html, especially: String constants must be quoted within the expression—single and double quotes are both acceptable, but must be paired appropriately (that is, a double quote (") does not match a single quote (')).

Comment: @piobyz I think there is a misunderstanding. My issue is how to deal with strings with random quotes (not necessarily paired). Let's say I have a string such as HE"LLO in the database. And I have the same string HE"LLO in the local database, and I need to compare them using a NSPredicate. How can I do it ?

Comment: How about [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"'HE"LLO'"]?

Comment: @piobyz Unable to parse the format string "'HE"LLO'"

Comment: @Patrick and this one? NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'HE"LLO'"]; and then use this string in NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:

Comment: @piobyz Again, Unable to parse the format string "'HE"LLO'"

Comment: But even if it works, I'm not sure how your approach deals with strings containing ' .

Comment: @piobyz Let's say a string like this one: This "is 'a complicated string

Comment: @Patrick: yes, I'm sure. Take a closer look at the accepted answer for the other question and compare it to your attempted solution. Also compare the other answer with Dave's; the two are equivalent, and they do resolve the posted error. If there's still an issue, it's an additional one. Also, you've edited the question enough to make it a different question, which isn't exactly kosher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
NSString *string = @"This \"is 'a complicated string";
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"editionString = %@", string];
```

---

When I `NSLog` this predicate, it shows:

```
EmptyFoundation[15294:707] editionString == "This \"is 'a complicated string"
```

So: no parsing error, and the predicate is built correctly.  If it doesn't work for you, then you haven't asked the right question.

Comment: It surely doesn't work for me.. It gives me a parsing error, because string is not an unique term.