# Fetching only Core Data objects that share a value for a particular attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a Core Data object with several attributes, one of which is called Category. This is a string that could take on any value, nothing that I can guarantee any knowledge of up front. I want to run a fetch that will return a list of Category values that are shared across all stored elements whose Tag value matches a given value. I'm not sure how to best describe this, so here's an example:

```
ObjectNumber     Tag     Category
---------------------------------
01               AAA     Red
02               AAA     Green
03               AAA     Blue

04               BBB     Blue
05               BBB     Red
06               BBB     Yellow

07               CCC     Blue
08               CCC     Yellow
09               CCC     Red
```

I want the results of my fetch to be a list of Categories that are shared across all objects whose Tag is in the set {AAA, BBB, CCC}, which in this case, would return ["Red", "Blue"], because those are the only categories shared among any objects whose tag is in the given set.

I'm hoping to find something that's as fast as possible, because when this app is run on a real project, there will be tens of thousands of objects in the database.

Comment: Phil have you tried using an `NSPredicate` with your fetch?

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure how to set it up in order to restrict the results to what I need.

Comment: I think this needs to step beyond NSPredicate, into SQL, in order to simply get an array of strings which are the attributes of a set of fetched objects.  Otherwise, process the result of the NSPredicate.  From my limited research into NSFetchRequest and other Core Data things, Apple recommends doing post-processing to get more fine-grained results.

Comment: Tom, that's how I was able to pull it off in Android. I'm hoping for a way to do it with predicates, but I have a feeling you're right.

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth I will post an answer shortly! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code sample I just wrote up, that should solve your filtration question.

I'm still learning the intricacies of NSFetchRequest and predicates, although it's not very complicated, after reading the documentation and experimenting.

```
NSArray *setoftags = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"AAA", @"BBB", nil];
NSFetchRequest * request;
NSMutableSet *tagcategoriesset = nil;
for (NSString *tag in setoftags) {

    request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ObjectWithCategories"];
    NSPredicate *tagPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"Tag", tag];
    request.predicate = tagPredicate;
    NSArray *objects;
    NSError *err;
    NSMutableSet *tagcategories = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    if ( (objects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err]) == nil) {
        // error
        NSLog(@"There was an error:\n%@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        // fetch request succeeded


        // Ignore any unused tags
        if ( [objects count] == 0) continue;

        // Collect the Category attribute into a mutable set
        for(NSManagedObject *obj in objects) {
            [tagcategories addObject: [(id)obj Category]];
        }

        // First assign, later intersect the tagcategories
        if (tagcategoriesset == nil) {
            tagcategoriesset = tagcategories;
        }
        else {
            [tagcategoriesset intersectSet: tagcategories];
        }
    }
}

NSArray *finalCategories = [tagcategoriesset allObjects];
```

Here's another SO Q&A for further discussion: [using NSPredicate with a set of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418027/using-nspredicate-with-a-set-of-answers)

Comment: Thank you Tom. This looks like it will get me on the right track.

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth I just scanned through andrewbuilder's code, and it misses the collective uniquing of categories across tags, but mine does too. Give me a minute. :)

Comment: @TomPace yes it misses, but to be clear my code was provided as examples from which a solution could be extrapolated. Maybe I should make that more clear in my answer?

Comment: @andrewbuilder Maybe it would be cool to see a more-clear answer, but I have re-read the question, and there is an awkward logical relationship, a many-to-many relationship with an in-memory table being built on-the-fly.

Comment: @TomPace fair comment. I'll have a look at it too and see if I can wrangle `NSPredicate` into a solution.

Comment: @TomPace, I accepted your answer because I did get it working based on the code you gave me. I also want to thank andrewbuilder for the link to the documentation, I will keep it handy. My next task is to do this one level deeper, if that even makes any sense, where I must find a set of shared properties inside a set of shared properties inside.... you get the idea. I'll save this until tomorrow :-).

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth I finished a full solution for your problem, sort of an exercise.  My answer has been updated. :)  Thanks

Comment: @andrewbuilder I updated with a full solution, tag-by-tag set intersecting.  It took a few re-readings of the question to really get the algorithm. SO keeps our minds sharp!

Comment: @TomPace nice work! Intriguing scenario, keeps the brain working.

Comment: @TomPace, If I could accept your answer a second time, I would! The revised answer does exactly what I needed, with only a few modifications to fit my actual situation. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

These are all good articles that helped me better understand `NSPredicate`. I highly recommend these as worthwhile reading.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789)

[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) by Mattt Thompson

[Using NSPredicate to Filter Data](http://www.peterfriese.de/using-nspredicate-to-filter-data/) by Peter Friese

---

This is an **example** of a simple `NSPredicate`...

```
NSString *key = @"Category";
NSString *value = @"Red";
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, value]
```

This is an **example** of a more complicated `NSPredicate`...

```
NSString *key = @"Category";
NSString *value1 = @"Red";
NSString *value2 = @"Blue";
NSPredicate *predicateRed = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", key, value1];
NSPredicate *predicateBlue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", key, value2];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicateRed, predicateBlue]];
```

I used this format to demonstrate what can be achieved. To be clear this second example could also be more simply written...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(%K == %@) || (%K == %@)", key, value1, key, value2];
```

These examples are not intended to be the solution, however are provided to demonstrate the mechanics to help you develop a solution.

Hope that helps.